# How to check if given username has at least one letter in ruby

Tags: regex, ruby

I have this regex:

```
^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])
```

But this requires both letter and number. What I need to check if username has either full of letters like `pratha` or letters with numbers `pratha123` or `123pratha` but not just numbers `1234156`

I couldn't adjust this regex to fit my needs. How can i adjust to work like this?

Note that, there is no sequence like it should start with letter or not. It can start with number or letter but it should have at least one letter. I just want to discard numbers-only. And username is just `a-zA-Z0-9`. So no Unicode chars.

Using Ruby `2.6.3`

**Demo**: https://rubular.com/r/WT9VCAphYyEMIc

**Update**: I discovered that this pattern also allows spaces. It shouldn't.

Comment: Don’t be reluctant to reassign the greenie If a better answer turns up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand you want to determine if the string has only letters and numbers and at least one letter. You could use the following regular expression:

```
r = /\A\p{Alnum}*\p{L}\p{Alnum}*\z/
```

This reads, "match a start-of-string anchor, followed by zero or more alphanumeric (Unicode) characters (letters or numbers), followed by a letter, followed by zero or more alphanumeric characters, followed by an end-of-string anchor".

```
"12abc34".match?(r) #=> true
"1234567".match?(r) #=> false
"=12abc3".match?(r) #=> false
"".match?(r)        #=> false
```

Another way:

```
r = /\A(?=.*\p{L})\p{Alnum}*\z/
```

This reads, "match a start-of-string anchor, followed by a letter preceded by zero or more of characters, in a *positive lookahead* (which consumes no characters), followed by zero or more alphanumeric characters, followed by an end-of-string anchor".

Comment: How does the positive lookahead manage to look through the whole string? I thought it only looked at the first character.

Comment: I get it now, the `.*` matches any length of any characters as long as it's followed by a letter.

Comment: Yes, that's right, and after it matches (assuming it does), the search continues from the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 3):

At least one letter:

```
username.count("a-zA-Z") > 0
```

username is just a-zA-Z0-9, so no Unicode chars:

```
username.count("^a-zA-Z0-9") == 0
```

Comment: I was not aware that characters could be negated when using `String#count`. Best answer!

Answer (score 1):

I am sure there is a more clever way to do this but that one does the job.

```
USERNAME_REGEX = /\A[a-z0-9]*[a-z]+[a-z0-9]*\z/i
if username.match USERNAME_REGEX
  # It matches
else
  # It does not match
end
```

The `\A` at the beginning and the `\z` at the end makes sure that the whole string matches the regex, otherwise it would just check if it contains it.

The trick is to make sure there is at least one letter in the middle and 0 or many letters or numbers before and after.

I assumes you wanted ascii characters but if you want UTF-8 instead, it should be easy to change.

Comment: @CarySwoveland That's weird, it is like the option "m" is on by default for multiline matches.

Comment: @CarySwoveland alright I see. I fixed my answer. In ruby `^` and `$` always refer to a line. Whereas `\A` and `\z` are the beginning and end of the whole string. That is actually useful once you know it but to be honest differences in regexp from one language to another are the gates of hell ;-)

Comment: @pratha If you struggle with another regexp, here a website I used to try specifically ruby regexps: https://rubular.com/